# Annotation for unique constraint for single column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I would like to instruct Hibernate to create unique constraint on a single column. I have set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in the hibernate configuration and my code is shown below:

```
@Column(name = "program_id",unique=true)
@Length(min = 0, max = 10)
private String programID;
```

I don't see any unique index created on the table in MySQL. What am I suppose to do to get it working ?

Comment: What is the underlying DB system?

Comment: Have you tried inserting entities with identical programIDs?

Comment: Yes I have. It nicely went into the table.